# Change multidimensional arrray key name

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I already have the following array;

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Categorie 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Categorie 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => Categorie 3
    )
)
```

And what I would like to get is this (for the select dropdown form in CodeIgniter)

```
 array(
     '1'  => 'Categorie 1',
     '2'    => 'Categorie 2',
     '3'   => 'Categorie 3'
 );
```

I have been searching for this for the rest 2 hours but still don't even know what is the correct title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$newArray();
foreach ($oldArray as $k => $v) {
    $newArray[$v['id']] = $v['name'];
}
```

You could use `$oldArray as $v` or use a different name as key.

Comment: Can't believe I was 5 minutes late when I submitted this.

Comment: Thank you, it worked like a charm but I guess there is a mistake in the key variable. Please fix it.

Comment: Speed and accuracy is the name of game.

Comment: I just fixed the key name. It should work well for you now. Key just had to be different from the Value.

Comment: Why do I always make a correction and someone's name shows up as the editor? I can't see anything different from my last edit right now. Is it done in favour of people with high reputations? Just asking! Everything is just as my last edit. Maybe the system just picks based on time rather than actual edits.

Comment: To improve upon the answer , you do not even need $k. Just need "foreach  ( $oldarray as $v )"

Comment: @StewardGodwinJornsen please see http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15191677/revisions to see the differences. User just tidied up your post.

Comment: hmm, where you get that link from? smart